Unique proof existence question: zero power series implies zero value coefficients
Within the Graduate texts in mathematics: Complex Analysis by Serge Lang, on pg 62, he iterates
 "allow for  $h(t)=f(T)-g(T)=\sum(a_{n}-b_{n})T^{n}$. $h(x)=0$, for an infinite set of points $x,$ $\lim{h(x) \rightarrow 0}$ as a point of accumulation"
Lang concludes stating that if $h(T)$ is the zero power series, then $a_{n}=b_{n}$, or rather, zero-value coefficients $c_{n} = a_{n}-b_{n}$, $h(t)=\sum c_{n}T^{n}$
I wrote a proof please inform me of the errors of my ways using words, english recommended math preferred.
Proof. [1]
$$0=a_{n-0}x^{0}+a_{n-1}x^{1}+\cdots+a_{0}x^{n}$$
With 0 is the (*sequential point of accumulation within this epsilon neighborhood.
it follows, [2]
$$\sum^{k}_{n=0} a_{n-k} x^{n} =(\frac{1}{1-a^{\frac{1}{n}}_{n-k}x})=\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} \frac {1}{r}$$
however we see part of a solution within the geometric series [3]
$$({1-a^{\frac{1}{n}}_{n-k}x})=\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} r$$
or [4]
$$(\frac{|1-r|}{x})^{n}=a_{k-n}$$
if wlog, then the following axioms
$$a_{k-n}>x^{n},a_{k-n}<x^{-n}$$
Further [5]
$\frac {1}{x}$ exhibits the same behavior as $\frac {r}{x}$ as $x \to 0$ and $r \to \infty$
Therefore [6]
$$(\frac{|1-r|}{x} \to 0)^{n}=a_{k-n}$$
Which As [7]
wlog $n$ may $ \rightarrow \infty$ ;$a_{k-n}$ definitively must equate 0.
concluding; $ |x|<1 \forall x$
I 想 , my use of limitations on this exercise is without prior formal introduction or instruction outside of the texts. may the coefficients $a_{k-n} be used arbitrarily, wlog, rather without considering each coefficients equate zero.
什么思考做?

$a_j$ are arbitrary constants, so the sum is not in general a geometric series at all.

While solution-verification questions are fine, please keep those guidelines in mind, and edit your question appropriately: "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

@aschepler $a_{p-f}$ are constantly 0, x is wlog a "constant", right[?], within an arbitrary sequence, articulated as $ |x|<1$ with a point of accumulation, zero. $ \sum_{n}^{k} (a_{k-n}^{\frac{1}{n}}x)^{n}$
